# Javascript variable access in HTML

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following JavaScript in a HTML page

```
<html>
<script>
    var simpleText = "hello_world";
    var finalSplitText = simpleText.split("_");
    var splitText = finalSplitText[0];
</script>

<body>
    <a href = test.html>I need the value of "splitText" variable here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the value of the variable "splitText" outside the script tags.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't get the value from outside of the script tag; the script tag injects the value somewhere else into the page. But to do that, you first need to wrap your function to be called only when the page is done loading.

Comment: Use the "innerHTML" value of the document element...

Comment: Well, technically you *could* do it with `<a href='test.html'><script>document.write(splitText);</script></a>`, but it's generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<html>
<script>
var simpleText = "hello_world";
var finalSplitText = simpleText.split("_");
var splitText = finalSplitText[0];

window.onload = function() {
       //when the document is finished loading, replace everything
       //between the <a ...> </a> tags with the value of splitText
   document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML=splitText;
} 

</script>

<body>
<a id="myLink" href = test.html></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var simpleText = "hello_world";
            var finalSplitText = simpleText.split("_");
            var splitText = finalSplitText[0];
            $("#target").text(splitText);
        });
</script>

<body>
<a id="target" href = test.html></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function putText() {
        var simpleText = "hello_world";
        var finalSplitText = simpleText.split("_");
        var splitText = finalSplitText[0];
        document.getElementById("destination").innerHTML = "I need the value of " + splitText + " variable here";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad = putText()>
    <a id="destination" href = test.html>I need the value of "splitText" variable here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In raw javascript, you'll want to put an id on your anchor tag and do this:

```
<html>
<script>
var simpleText = "hello_world";
var finalSplitText = simpleText.split("_");
var splitText = finalSplitText[0];

function insertText(){
    document.getElementById('someId').InnerHTML = splitText;}
</script>

<body onload="insertText()">
<a href = test.html id="someId">I need the value of "splitText" variable here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cKflA

Although, I must say that what you are asking to do is not a good way to do it. A good way is this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlkvJ

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make it work would be to put img element using onerror, and no src. This is a dirty workaround... But it fits.

```js
const data_ = {
  'd1'  : 'data_1',
  'd2'  : 'data_2',
};

function getData(n_, key_){
  n_.parentNode.innerHTML = data_[key_];
}
```

```html
<div><img src onerror="getData(this,'d1')" /></div>
<div><img src onerror="getData(this,'d2')" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The info inside the `<script>` tag is then processed inside it to access other parts. If you want to change the text inside another paragraph, then first give the paragraph an id, then set a variable to it using `getElementById([id])` to access it ([id] means the id you gave the paragraph). 
Next, use the `innerHTML` built-in variable with whatever your variable was called and a '**.**' (dot) to show that it is based on the paragraph. You can set it to whatever you want, but be aware that to set a paragraph to a tag (<...>), then you have to still put it in speech marks.

### Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <!--\|/id here-->
        <p id="myText"></p>
        <p id="myTextTag"></p>
        <script>
            <!--Here we retrieve the text and show what we want to write...
            var text = document.getElementById("myText");
            var tag = document.getElementById("myTextTag");
            var toWrite = "Hello"
            var toWriteTag = "<a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow</a>"
            <!--...and here we are actually affecting the text.-->
            text.innerHTML = toWrite
            tag.innerHTML = toWriteTag
        </script>
    <body>
<html>
```