# How Do I Use A Javascript Variable In An Href

Tags: javascript, html

Would something like this be possible?

```
<head>
<script>
var movie="Tag";
var link=("google.com/"+movie);
</script>
<a href=(link)>Click Me</a>
</head>
```

Please Help Me

Comment: You don't.  You can use an `onclick` though.

Comment: You -can- use anchor tags, you just need more javascript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845710/javascript-variable-access-in-html

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question ([`[javascript] url variable href`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+url+variable+href)). Most questions have been asked before.

Answer (score 2):

HTML does not work like a templating language. To do something like this, the source would look a bit more like this:

```
<body>
  <a href="#" id="some-random-id">Click Me</a>

  <script>
    var movie = "Tag";
    var link = "http://google.com/"+movie;
    document.getElementById('some-random-id').setAttribute('href', link);
  </script>
</body>
```

The difference is that we *first* created the HTML, and afterwards are using javascript to replace the link.

It's also possible to use Javascript to write all the HTML, but this is probably the easiest way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it takes a bit of coding.

In this case, you need to specify the full `url`, including the schema.

Then I gave the link an `id` attribute so that the JavaScipt code could find it and update the `href` with the new `url`.

```js
const movie="Tag";
const url= "https://google.com/"+movie;
const link = document.getElementById("test-link");

link.href = url;
```

```html
<a id="test-link" href="#">Click Me</a>
```