# How do I access JavaScript variable under Color portion of HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, web-component, aframe

I would like to access the variable "theSkyColour" inside the HTML code below as shown. May I know how do I access it as shown?

The following is the code I have written:

```js
function getSkyColour() {
  var theSkyColour = localStorage.getItem('skySet[enter image description here][1]ting');
}
```

```html
<a-sky id="skyColor" src="#sky" 
material="shader:gradient; topColor: <<I want to access theSkyColor here>>; bottomColor: <<I want to access theSkyColor here>> ; offset:0;"></a-sky>
```

I have viewed other answers like the one here: [Javascript variable access in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845710/javascript-variable-access-in-html), however, it did not work for me as I am unable to change the color of the sky in the viewing page.

I've created the following HTML pages.
 1. A settings page to adjust the color of the sky saved in a localStorage as "skyColor".
 2. A viewing page for the user to view the color of the sky.

The reason why I have an a-sky tag is that I am using aframe.io

Update: After attempting to use JavaScript along with localStorage Sessions:

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
function getSkyColor() {
  var theSkyColor = localStorage.getItem('skySetting');
}
getSkyColour()

var myAttr = "shader:gradient; topColor:"+theSkyColor+"; 
bottomColor:"+theSkyColor+"; offset:0;"
document.getElementById(‘skyColor’).setAttribute(“material”,myAttr)
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
  <a-sky id="skyColor" src="#sky" material="shader:gradient; offset:0;"></a-sky>
```

Unfortunately, it still does not work, as the display I get is not what I have expected, which is a night sky under the RGB color: 41 35 71. (See attached screenshot)

[Failed display of desired colors RGB 41 35 71](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehMhd.jpg)

[What I want and What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2oPI.jpg)

Comment: It's not possible to access javascript variable in html.

Comment: check this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: "It did not work for me" how? It is not very descriptive. Please update the snippet I made for you with your attempts - Also please tell us what framework has `<a-sky` tags

Comment: Tri this: `document.getElementById('skyColor').setAttribute('material', document.getElementById('skyColor').getAttribute('style')+'; color: '+getSkyColour());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using a framework like Angular or django, it is not possible to access variables in your HTML code, instead you can construct the attribute in your Javascript and add it to the element.

EX:

```
var myAttr = "shader:gradient; topColor:"+skyColor+"; bottomColor:"+skyColor+"; offset:0;"
$("#skyColor").attr("material",myAttr)
```

Update: without using jQuery:

```
<script>
function getSkyColour() {
  var theSkyColour = localStorage.getItem('skySetting');
}
getSkyColour()

var myAttr = "shader:gradient; topColor:"+theSkyColour+"; bottomColor:"+theSkyColour+"; offset:0;"
document.getElementById(‘skyColor’).setAttribute(“material”,myAttr)

</script>
```

Comment: For the second line  "$("#skyColor").attr("material",myAttr)" , may I know where should I place this line of code? Is this a PHP code? How do I use it?

Comment: This is a jQuery code, you need to have jQuery library in your application to use it. If you do not have jQuey library, I will suggest an alternative to it in pure JavaScript

Comment: I would like to use pure Javascript as well. However, like I mentioned in the original post, there is a problem of being unable to call it inside the HTML code with Javascript. So I'm confused. What should I do here if I would like to use pure Javascript?

Comment: Basically, any JavaScript you use goes inside “<script> your JavaScript </script>”

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code according to what you've specified. Unfortunately, the display still does not update according to the desired preferences. I have edited the original post to include the results shown on the browser, along with the codes I have used in the HTML code.

Could you advise? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I see that you have some attribute called "material", Check the documentation of it and see how colors are passed to it. Alternatively, if you want the background color to be set, use "style" attribute and set background color

Comment: also are you sure about the property "top-color"? check if such a property exists and usually in css, colors are specified in hex codes. Ex: white color is specified as "#fff"

Comment: Hi, I used "top-color" and "bottom-color" because this is being used in a aframe platform.

Check out https://github.com/zcanter/aframe-gradient-sky/blob/master/example/example.html where they also used "top-color" and "bottom-color". The "style" attribute does not seem to work for me unfortunately, could be because it is under an aframe-environment right now.

Comment: can you give me a link to working code? A fiddle would be better

Comment: Hi, can you go to :
https://github.com/leontxh/ICT2X01VRProject/tree/gh-pages

And go to freeroam.html to view the code?

Thanks

Comment: things you need to change:

Comment: 1. put the script below "body" tag(script is running before element is found)
2. change the css of element with id skyColor --- use the following class
    #skyColor{
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
3. Set "style" attribute in the way shown above(I tried by setting material attribute, It did not work, however with style attribute you can set background also)

Comment: Hi, I've tried your solution as shown on jsfiddle.net. However, I still can't get the color to change. As the color is dependent on RGB, I had to separate the 3 values to ensure that they are not lumped together as one and have commas to separate them. Unfortunately, I'm still obtain the results I want.

Could you provide any advice on this? I've seen other articles talking about how to code rgb colours into javascript, but they do not work for me.

I guess you can try debugging with rgb colours and see if it works on your end?

Comment: RGB Colours are represented as “#xxxxxx”. This is the standard form of colour representation, if not this you can use colour name like “blue”. The form in which you are expecting it to work is not gonna work... and moreover if it represents rgb, u can combine them and add a “#” before it

Comment: Noted on RGB colours represented using #xxxxxx. Take a look at the screenshot I have captured and updated in the original post. It shows that the sky color is still not being updated. I suspect it's because I need to change the "topcolor" and "bottomcolor" as compared to the background color. As it is a specific a-frame environment in a virtual reality environment, I don't think it's as simple as changing the background color. What is your advice? Thanks and sorry to keep troubling you.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea about a-frame, what I know is javascript and css, but there is a way to achieve what you are looking for, it’s called colour gradient. Have a look at the following link, maybe it might help

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, the link provided does not help. It doesn't help me change the attributes I want in the HTML code, which is topColor and bottomColor. If i change any other HTML attributes such as background, or styles, or whichever, it does not work in a-frame. So is there any other way I can change a specified attribute found in the a-frame, namely "topColor" and "bottomColor"? That was the whole premise of this question and it seems so difficult to resolve this.

Comment: I have no idea about a-frame, never used it.. probably someone else can help.. :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can’t, but you can change the function to update the color of the sky.

```
document.getElementById("skyColor").material = `defaultStylesInHere topColor:${localStorage.getItem("skyColor")};`;
```

**Update**

```
let setSkyColor = (val) => {
    localStorage.setItem('skyColor', `defaultStylesInHere topColor:${val};bottomColor:${val}`);
}
let loadSkyColor = () => {
    document.getElementById('skyColor').attributes.material = localStorage.getItem('skyColor');
}
```

**I can make full functions, but it should not be necessary**

You could also use JSON or Objects to set and grab sky properties

```
let app = {
    skyProp: {
        /*
        color: 'rgba(200, 200, 255, 1)',
        OR
        color: {
            default: {
                color: 'rgba(200, 200, 255, 1)',
                topColor: 'green',
            },
            night: {
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                bottomColor: 'rgba(155, 155, 155, 1)',
            }
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely want  `getAttribute("material")` here

Comment: Please do not use curly quotes - are you updating on a phone?

Comment: You can add comments as comments, no need to edit the post for that.

Comment: Yes, I am using a phone, it was stated at the bottom of my post

Comment: iPhones do normal quotes if you hold and drag on the quote

Comment: Hi, I typed the code as such:
  document.getElementById("theSky").material = 'defaultStylesInHere topColor:${localStorage.getItem("skyColor")};';


However, I didn't get the result I want. Does this help to change the topColor and bottomColor attribute of the HTML element?

The code for the HTML element is as such:

  <a-sky id="theSky" src="#sky" material="shader:gradient; topColor:41 35 71; bottomColor:41 35 71; offset:0;"></a-sky>

Comment: I will try rewriting it

Answer (score 0):

check out the snippets for getting and setting attributesin an a-frame component. Refer to the following documentation:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/entity.html#getattribute-componentname

It explains very well how to get and how to set values from component properties and sub-properties:

**Get Property**

[image]

**Set Property**
[image]

Comment: Does this apply in my scenario, considering that I am accessing a local session? I am using some aframe components, however, I am not sure if it works since I am changing a local session on another HTML page. 

Could you advise if there is an alternative for using local sessions storage?

Comment: I don't think templating is available for aframe at component sub-properties level, as they're one string. I think you can modify the values right after initialization of the frame. Not sure how it is done yet!